# react-router changes URL but does not render component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

While using `react-router`, I'm running into the issue where the URL changes, but does not actually render the component.
Here's how my code looks like.

`history.js`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

`index.js`

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from './history';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`App`

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                <Route path="/onDemandProductSearch" component={OnDemandProductSearch} />
            </Switch>
        );
    };
};
```

I have a header (called `Header`) that gets displayed on every component, it looks like this:

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">Cirrus</Link>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul className="navbar-nav">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                        <Link to="/onDemandProductSearch" className="nav-link">On Demand Products</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

I read some other questions, which were similar, but people were using `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router`, which isn't my case.

Just FYI, my app structure is like this:

```
My-App
|- src
    |- index.js
    |- history.js
    |- components
        |- App.js
        |- Header.js
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using Router instead of BrowserRouter? Typically you should be using BrowserRouter which does a good job to keep your UI in sync with your URL. Refer to this [link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter)

Comment: Yes, so the goal is to maintain history. I have a form who's state needs to be kept even after navigating away.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your `Route` component you are passing a component prop but the right way to do that is just wrap the wanted component. Like this

```
<Route path='/onDemandProductSearch'> <OnDemandProductSearch/> </Route>
```

Notice!
React does not render the components when the url is changing only the `route params` and the component  was already loaded. If that is your case What you should do is to pass the route params to the `useEffect` method inside the dependencies array and that will cause the component to be rerenderd when the url will change.

```
const paramData = useParams();
useEffect(()=>{
Some logic when your component gets rendered...},[paramData])}
```

Comment: So you recommend using this strategy in the component I want rendered?

Comment: Yes, if you have this path : `a.b.c/:userName'  you should get the user name from the use params and put it into the dependencies array, it should solve the problem

Comment: Could you help me with a non-hook solution? Not too familiar with hooks!

Comment: I want to understand, from which path to which path the change occurs. From '/' to '/onDemandProductSearch'?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not understood the problem from start. The problem is that in your `Route` component you are passing a component prop but the right way to do that is just wrap the wanted component. Like this ``` <Route path='/onDemandProductSearch'> <OnDemandProductSearch/> </Route>```

Comment: Happens to any route I try navigating to (`/` to `/onDemandProductSearch` or vice-versa). Only if I refresh the page does the component render.

Answer (score -1):

just use `<a href="your_url"></a>` instead of `<Link to="your_url"></Link>` tag

It's work for me

```
<Card>
    <Link to={`/menu/${dish.id}`}>
         <CardImg width="100%" src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
         <CardImgOverlay >
             <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
         </CardImgOverlay>
    </Link>
</Card>
```

I have changed the above code to below

```
<Card>
      <a href={`/menu/${dish.id}`}>
          <CardImg width="100%" src={baseUrl + dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
          <CardImgOverlay >
               <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
          </CardImgOverlay>
      </a>
</Card>
```

Comment: <Link> does not always do the same thing as `<a>`. Having a better understanding of the question might help in coming up with a better and more descriptive answer.